# Call google app engine from google cloud function?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-functions

I want to be able to Call google app engine from google cloud function is it possible? cant find any solution

Answer (score 0):

From [Google's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/ruby/communicating-between-services)

> The simplest approach for communicating with your App Engine service is to send targeted HTTP requests, where the URL includes the name or ID of a resource.